# Webpack and GoogleApis endpoint path issues

Tags: node.js, webpack, google-api, google-api-client, webpack-2

I'm trying to use googleapis in a webpack project. Whenever I invoke

```
static getApi = () => {
    google.sheets('v4');
}
```

I get the following `Error: Unable to load endpoint ../apis/sheets("v4"): Cannot find module "."`
Originating from line 50 of `googleapis/lib/googleapis.js`, which is basically `var Endpoint = require(endpointPath);`.

I tried looking into endpointPath, but it happens to be the correct one: `node_modules/googleapis/apis/sheets/v4`

My webpack.config.js is presented below:

```
module.exports = {
   entry: ['babel-polyfill','./src/index.js'],
   target: 'async-node', // Improved performance in node version 6+
   node: {
     __dirname: true
   },
   output: {
     filename: './dist/bundle.js',
     libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
   },
   module: {
     rules: [
      {
    test: /\.(graphql|gql)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'graphql-tag/loader'
  },
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['env'],
          plugins: [require('babel-plugin-transform-class-properties')]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map'
}
```

Removing the

```
node: {
  __dirname: true
},
```

results in getting a `ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/apis'` originating from line 62 of the aforementioned googleapis.js

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

As per this [github issue comment](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/403#issuecomment-211153097), googleapis node client should be excluded from any server side bundling mechanism.

> googleapis (google-api-nodejs-client) will work in Node.js. Excluding
>   googleapis from any server-side bundle (just let Node's module system
>   load it for you) is the best option.